# NSOpenGLView in NSSplitView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, macos-carbon, splitter

When i put an NSOpenglView in NSSplitView, a problem occurs while dragging splitter.
The openGLView and SplitView are resizing asynchronously. i found a solution in apple mail list thread http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/GLChildWindowDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

and i found a solution with some carbon calls. but now i get link error (only in release mode).

so i'v got two questions - is there any cocoa way to fix the splitter - gl problem?
if no - how can i fix carbon linker errors in release mode?

Comment: Probably deprecated carbon wrapers are sending the linking error. On the other hand I read that OpenGL and UIKit elements just don't play right... I'll recommend using a single Framework is it possible.

Comment: There's no UIKit here, it's a Cocoa/Mac question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.

the right way is to implement thees methods in your MYWindow : NSWindow

```
BOOL needsEnableUpdate;

-(void)disableUpdatesUntilFlush
{
    if(!needsEnableUpdate)
        NSDisableScreenUpdates();
    needsEnableUpdate = YES;
}

-(void)flushWindow
{
    [super flushWindow];
    if(needsEnableUpdate)
    {
        needsEnableUpdate = NO;
        NSEnableScreenUpdates();
    }
}
```

and in NSSplitterView delegate implement

```
#pragma mark NSSplitView Delegate
-(void)splitViewWillResizeSubviews:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [window disableUpdatesUntilFlush];
}
```

my problem was that i tried to use carbon calls:

```
DisableScreenUpdates();
EnableScreenUpdates();
```

instead of cocoa ones:

```
NSDisableScreenUpdates();
NSEnableScreenUpdates();
```

Comment: Just wanted to say THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. You rock.

Comment: For the shake of clarity, I would write:

-(void)disableUpdatesUntilFlush
{
    if(!needsEnableUpdate) {
        NSDisableScreenUpdates();
        needsEnableUpdate = YES;
    }
}